# return the last comment of each post in a list of posts mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the next tables

```
posts:
id_post,post

comments
id_comment,id_post,comment
```

Whit the next SQL statement I return the list of posts (20) with a unique comment...

```
SELECT 
p.*,
c.comment
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN comments c ON c.id_post = p.id_post
WHERE 1
GROUP BY p.id_post 
ORDER BY p.id_post DESC 
LIMIT 20
```

In php

```
while(){

 echo $res[post]."-".$res[comment]."<br>";
}
```

What I expect (the last comment of each commented post)

```
POST 4 -
 COMMENT 4 D

POST 3 -

POST 2 -
  COMMENT 2 F

POST 1 -
```

What I get (the first comment of each commented post)

```
POST 4 -
 COMMENT 4 A

POST 3 -

POST 2 -
  COMMENT 2 A

POST 1 -
```

**How do I fix this?**

Comment: Note that in the absence of any aggregating functions, a GROUP BY clause is never  appropriate. For further help, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

You can use the concept of ranks. Just modify the variable @intRank to get the @intRank(th) comment.

```
SET @intRank:= 1; 
SET @intPrevPostId := -1;
SELECT id_posts, id_comment, `comment`
FROM
(
    SELECT posts.id_posts, comments.id_comment, comments.`comment`,
    IF(@intPrevPostId = comments.id_posts, @intRank:= @intRank+1, @intRank := 1) AS rank,
            @intPrevPostId := comments.id_posts
    FROM posts
    LEFT JOIN comments ON comments.id_posts = posts.id_posts
    ORDER BY comments.id_comment
) AS inner_table
WHERE inner_table.rank = 1 OR inner_table.rank IS NULL
```

Answer (score -1):

Collect every last `comment` of every `post` by inserting a subquery that fetches them. In that subquery, join the the two tables and sort the `comments` records in descending order, in that case we can get the last element by limiting the query into one record for each comment query.

```
SELECT (
      SELECT * FROM comments
      INNER JOIN posts.id = comments.post_id
      ORDER BY comments.date_added DESC
      LIMIT 1
    ) FROM posts;
```

Comment: looks good...but is there a way to avoid using subqueries?

Comment: You definitely gonna use subqueries for your problem.

Comment: Thanks @NicoHaase for noticing, just updated my answer.

Comment: you should check if your answer gather expertise enough before posting it.

Comment: otherwise, you make lose OP time..!!